# What rafters would be most supportive

Tags: shed

To preface i have never built anything this big. I am building a 12x14 chicken coop and I’m coming off of a blueprint i purchased online. I am starting to build rafters which are 2x4’s. The plans said if the span is over 10’ then i need to add a bottom chord. I live in Texas and we get some ice at times but mainly have high winds. This will be a tin roof with no plywood under it. Should i use 2x6’s or stick with the 2x4’s? Should i build with bottom chord?

Comment: Hi Courtney,  does the an mention that its suitable for snow or ice? Does it mention what climate zone or country its for?

Answer (score 1):

Bigger can be better, however the blueprints call for 2x4s.

Use southern yellow pine for the rafters and the bottom chord.

The wind will be an issue depending on the way the roofing is attached. The type is unknown, but shoot for a screw anchor that penetrates the 2x4s at least 2 inches.

Winds can topple the entire coop. Have a system to anchor the entire structure to the earth. Again not knowing the details of the design I cannot comment on exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

Where I am, in Canada, a building that size without bottom chords (or a structural ridge beam) will fail eventually. The ridge will sag and the walls will bow out. I can see a couple sheds around that have this problem.

https://inspectapedia.com/structure/Roof_Collapse_Forces.php

But we have snow loads, so maybe it's different in Texas.